# How to use BiConsumer to accept an object having an object, list of strings, and variables?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to use BiConsumer to accept an object that contains variables, an object and a list of strings in Java.  I am not sure how to set the values into one object if using just BiConsumer.  Maybe, if I tried to wrap Student object in a List and pass it into a new Student might help, but so far I get a null object. I haven't seen a lot of post with object containing just variables in one object and using BiConsumer.

```
@Test
public void testStudent() {
    List<Object> objectList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    Student student = new Student();

    StudentLevel studentLevel = new StudentLevel("freshman", true);
    List<String> studentLists = Arrays.asList("Maria", "Jose", "Juan");
    Student student1 = new Student("Maria", "Lopez", "A", studentLevel, studentLists);
    objectList1.add(student1);

    BiConsumer<Object, List<Object>> biconsumer = (obj, list) -> {
      for (Object object: list) {
        // set and get but how?
        // obj = object;
      }
    };

    // To accept values from the object list see below for desired output
    biconsumer.accept(student, objectList1); 
    
    // For debugging purpose
    System.out.println("All Student: " + student);
}
```

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String grade;
    private StudentLevel studentGrade;
    private List<String> studentList;

    public Student(final String name, final String lastName, final String grade, final StudentLevel studentGrade, final List<String> studentList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.studentGrade = studentGrade;
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public StudentLevel getStudentGrade() {
        return studentGrade;
    }

    public void setStudentGrade(StudentLevel studentGrade) {
        this.studentGrade = studentGrade;
    }

    public List<String> getStudentList() {
        return studentList;
    }

    public void setStudentList(List<String> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }
}
```

```
public class StudentLevel {

    private String level;
    private Boolean pass;

    public StudentLevel(final String level, final Boolean pass){
        this.level = level;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(String level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public Boolean getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(Boolean pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }
}
```

Desired output:

```
student = {Student@887} 
  name = "Maria"
  lastName = "Lopez"
  grade = "A"
  studentGrade = {StudentLevel@889} 
    level = "freshman"
    pass = {Boolean@906} true
  studentList = {Arrays$ArrayList@890}  size = 3
    0 = "Maria"
    1 = "Jose"
    2 = "Juan"
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you expect the lines `biconsumer.accept(student, objectList1);
    System.out.println("All Student: " + student);` to do?

Comment: I updated that part, see desired output

Comment: What do you think that `biconsumer.accept(student, objectList1);` does? What do you want it to do?

Comment: I think it accepts values for that object, and i have seen online resources to do that so not sure how i should approach it.

Comment: I still have no idea what you are trying to do with the BiConsumer. Please edit your question and give a much fuller description of the what effect you want it to have.

Comment: @tgdavies got the answer for this post! see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning local reference of `object` to `obj` (won't copy the values)

```
obj = object; // means, student = object
```

no change will be reflected outside the scope of the consumer, instead, you need to modify the state using setters as:

```
((Student) obj).setName(((Student) object).getName());
obj = object; // after this point, student object won't be accessible in the current scope.
```

Note: You should have getters and setters to access private properties outside `Student` class, and this example just demonstrates the working by assigning `name` property.

Reference:

• [Classes and Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Comment: I do have those getters and setters, just to simplify in this post but posted already.  I want to use biconsumer and yes obj = object wont copy so prefer to have the entire object with its values and not just one variable like you mentioned for setName

Comment: @user2537246 Please read the answer carefully, specifically the `Note` part. You have another question then post it as a separate question (for the best experience for all the members). Usually, we (SO members often) don't add notes especially when an example is enough to show a solution.

Comment: I will do that!

Comment: Thank you, you can look into Generics in Java to simply copying data via a method, or probably create a method in Student class for the copying process, Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much @Pavneet_Singh I will look into Generics in Java to copy data via a method...

Comment: Why do you keep the pointless assignment when you already understood that it is pointless?

Comment: Commented out so there is no confusion.  Yeah i shouldn't not done that, learning about Biconsumer... thanks.